# Problem with loading Laravel Nova in production site

Tags: laravel-nova

I recently migrated to nova 4.26.0. I followed the migration guide as well. https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/upgrade.html. It's now working in local environment. But getting empty page with browser console error.

Here is the error I am getting:

[image: nova error]